# How to Assign an object to the hastable value in C#

Tags: c#

Here is my code

```
class Program
{

    public static IADXVoice ADXVoice1 = new Envox.ADXVoice.ADXVoice();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Hashtable objhashmap = new Hashtable();
        objhashmap.Add(8533, ADXVoice1);
        ICollection keytest = objhashmap.Values;
        ICollection keytest1 = objhashmap.Keys;

        foreach (int key in objhashmap.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", key, objhashmap[key]);
            //Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", key, objhashmap[key]);
            ADXVoice obj = objhashmap[key];// Am getting convert type error as Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Envox.ADXVoice.ADXVoice'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

In above code am not able to assign the hashtable value to the new object created for my dll used in code.

My requirement is taking the objects in hashtable and at needed time i want to assign in other places example shown in above code.

Comment: Do you expect the keys to be always of type `int`, and values to be always of type `IADXVoice`? If yes, then you can use a dictionary instead.

Answer (score 1):

> You need to provide type cast information. **objhashmap[key]** returns
> plain objects so you must cast them.
>
> This code might throw exceptions. Casting is a delicate operation. If the cast was applied to a
> different type, the statement could throw an InvalidCastException. You
> can avoid this by using the is or as-statements.

Cast it as below:

```
ADXVoice obj= objhashmap[key] as ADXVoice;
```

Refer the below link to know that how to use HashTable correctly:
[C# Hashtable](http://www.dotnetperls.com/hashtable)
[Hashtable Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx)